# How does the 'createApplication()' function work in ExpressJS source code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to understand line by line how the Express library works. So what I understand is when we import and call 'express()' function in our codebase, execution control would go to the ExpressJS library and look for the default export (in its Index.js).

**Index.js**

```
/*!
 * express
 * Copyright(c) 2009-2013 TJ Holowaychuk
 * Copyright(c) 2013 Roman Shtylman
 * Copyright(c) 2014-2015 Douglas Christopher Wilson
 * MIT Licensed
 */

'use strict';

module.exports = require('./lib/express');
```

Here, the execution control would go to './lib/express' and look for its default export.

**./lib/express.js**

```
/*!
 * express
 * Copyright(c) 2009-2013 TJ Holowaychuk
 * Copyright(c) 2013 Roman Shtylman
 * Copyright(c) 2014-2015 Douglas Christopher Wilson
 * MIT Licensed
 */

'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var mixin = require('merge-descriptors');
var proto = require('./application');
var Route = require('./router/route');
var Router = require('./router');
var req = require('./request');
var res = require('./response');

/**
 * Expose `createApplication()`.
 */

exports = module.exports = createApplication;

/**
 * Create an express application.
 *
 * @return {Function}
 * @api public
 */

function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  app.init();
  return app;
}

/**
 * Expose the prototypes.
 */

exports.application = proto;
exports.request = req;
exports.response = res;

/**
 * Expose constructors.
 */

exports.Route = Route;
exports.Router = Router;

/**
 * Expose middleware
 */

exports.json = bodyParser.json
exports.query = require('./middleware/query');
exports.raw = bodyParser.raw
exports.static = require('serve-static');
exports.text = bodyParser.text
exports.urlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded

/**
 * Replace removed middleware with an appropriate error message.
 */

var removedMiddlewares = [
  'bodyParser',
  'compress',
  'cookieSession',
  'session',
  'logger',
  'cookieParser',
  'favicon',
  'responseTime',
  'errorHandler',
  'timeout',
  'methodOverride',
  'vhost',
  'csrf',
  'directory',
  'limit',
  'multipart',
  'staticCache'
]

removedMiddlewares.forEach(function (name) {
  Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
    get: function () {
      throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.');
    },
    configurable: true
  });
});
```

The default export here seems to be 'createApplication()' factory function.

```
var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };
```

But what I do not understand is how we are calling the 'app.handle()' method when we have just freshly declared 'app' a line above. It should have no properties/methods right? How does it then work?

I tried to debug it line by line using VS Code, but it just skips all the breakpoints I put in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what I do not understand is how we are calling the 'app.handle()'
> method when we have just freshly declared 'app' a line above

This works because the code within the `app` function, specifically the `app.handle()` line of code, is not being executed when the `app` function is created. The code within the function is evaluated at some point in the future when `app()` is invoked in some way, but it's not evaluated at the time the `app` function is created:

```js
//  v--- Gets created and set to a function
var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next); // This `app` is used at some point in the future when this function is called, by that time `app` has been updated to have the `.handle()` method.
};
```

The `app` variable within the `function` refers to the `app` variable in the scope outside of the function (ie the one we just created), and so changes made to the `app` variable outside of the function before the function is called will also apply to the `app` variable within the function, allowing methods such as `handle()` to be used.

> It should have no properties/methods right?

No, that would only be the case if that function was being executed right away without `app` being modified or updated in any way, but we can see that is not the case, as `app()` is not being called, and we can see below the `var app = function(...) {...}` line that `app` is being modified.

Specifically, the `.handle` method is being added by this line:

```js
mixin(app, proto, false);
```

This merges the properties from the object `proto` into the `app` function object using the [merge-descriptors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-descriptors) package (ie: the `mixin` function). We can also see that `proto` is imported from the `./application.js` file in express which exports its own object that has its [own `handle` method](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L165C7-L165C7):

```js
app.handle = function handle(req, res, callback) {
  var router = this._router;

  // final handler
  var done = callback || finalhandler(req, res, {
    env: this.get('env'),
    onerror: logerror.bind(this)
  });

  // no routes
  if (!router) {
    debug('no routes defined on app');
    done();
    return;
  }

  router.handle(req, res, done);
};
```

---

For a simpler example on what's going on, the same principles apply in this example with different variable names for the object and the function. The `foo` function created forms what's called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the `obj` variable, and so changes to `obj` will be visible to the function once it's eventually executed:

```js
const obj = {};

const foo = function() { // When `foo` is created, `obj` doesn't have any properties 
  console.log(obj.x); // When this function is executed, `obj` in the surrounding scope has been updated to have an `x` property which can be printed 
}
obj.x = 1;
foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

While the code assigns a function to the app that would call method on the app, the function is never actually called until the method exists.

I have created a simplified example below. As you can see I assign the

```js
var app = function() {
  app.handle();
}

try {app();} catch (error) {console.error(error.name);} // fails with TypeError

app.handle = () => console.log("Hello World");
app(); // logs "Hello World"
```

In express 2 lines after the function you got confused about we have a line

```
  mixin(app, proto, false);
```

Which assigns the handle property to the app.

```
app.handle = function handle(req, res, callback) {
  var router = this._router;

  // final handler
  var done = callback || finalhandler(req, res, {
    env: this.get('env'),
    onerror: logerror.bind(this)
  });

  // no routes
  if (!router) {
    debug('no routes defined on app');
    done();
    return;
  }

  router.handle(req, res, done);
};
```